# JQuery Ajax returned blank data

Tags: jquery

I am learning how to use JQuery to help check data availability.

I have written a function in a Controller for checking data input, and the URL is like this:
http://www.mywebsite.com/controllers/action/avariable

But the returned data was blank.

```
<script language="javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){  
        $(document).change(function(){ 
            var usr = $("#data\\[User\\]\\[name\\]").val();
            $.post{"http://www.mywebsite.com/controllers/action/",
                usr,
                function(msg){alert(msg);}
            }
        });
    });   
</script>

<div id="username">
    <input type=text name="data[User][name]" id="data[User][name]">
</div>
```

Here is the code of the Action:

```
function action($data=null){
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $result2=$this->__avail($data);           
    if($result2==1)
        {return "OK";}
    else
        {return "NOT";}           
}
```

Comment: Does the correct data arrive at your server? In your server code you have once `action($data=null)` but `$this->__avail($udata)`

Comment: Do you get a response when you make a regular http post?

Comment: Did you alert(usr); to make sure you don't have garbage in?  Also, is the URL you're posting to on the same domain as the current page?  If not, your request will be denied due to the useless Same Origin Policy (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should get known with [FireBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/)

Your JavaScript looks extra wrong :)

First of all, inline javascripts should be formatted like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Than check out the [jQuery.post() docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) and overall javascript syntax...